# angular post request [object%20Object] error

Tags: angular, typescript, crud

I want to update the current user on the home page with the following post request. url: "http:...../user" and the url required for the post should be: "http:......./user/id" but the url is sent as **http:/...../user/[object%20Object]** and I get an error. how should I go about fixing this?

Service;

```
updateUser(id: number): Observable<User> {
  return this.http.put<User>(`${this.url}/${id}`, id)
}
```

User.ts;

```
export interface User {
  id: number
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  username: string
  mail: string
  password: string
}
```

home.component;

```
updateUser(id: number) {
  this.router.navigate(['update', id]);
}
```

update.component;

```
export class UpdateUserComponent implements OnInit {

  user?: User
  data: any

constructor(private service: AppService, private route: 
ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  form = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    lastName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    username: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    mail: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  })

  submit() {
    this.data = this.form.value
    console.log(this.data)

    this.service.updateUser(this.data).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
    })

    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }

}
```

Comment: Instead of posting image, post your code

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing only one parameter to your `udateUser` method in the service and that is not `id` but the whole form value object thats why its showing `[Object%20Object]`.

update the code inside your service and pass id and data two parameters

```
updateUser(id: number, data: User): Observable<User> { 
 return this.http.put<User>(`${this.url}/${id}`, data)
}
```

modify submit method inside `update.component.ts` file to get id from route param and pass to `updateUser` service method.

```
submit() { 
  this.data = this.form.value;
  const id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
  this.service.updateUser(id, this.data).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data)
  })
```

Hope this works

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the entire form into the service that is expecting just an id.
You need to rewrite the service and send id and form value!

Comment: I get the id value from the database. how can I send only the id value. i just started learning angular and unfortunately I don't know much about this subject